# Alternate Grid row colors?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, grid

Is it possible to attach a style or define a property in the WPF `System.Windows.Controls.Grid` in order to alternate the color of the rows(or columns)?

I need that User be able to place a grid placeholder (something similar to CrystalReports)... It can parameter the grid, but the grid (in View) will not contain any data.

Comment: The `Grid` is a layout item - for a data you should be using a `DataGrid` which has alternating row colouring built in.

Comment: @ChrisF: I don't need any data. Just a grid paceholder.

Comment: @serhio - it might help to show a mockup of what you want to achieve.

Comment: In fact, for me is equal what control to use, I really could use a Datagrid...

Comment: Then I'd suggest you use a DataGrid and use the built-in alternate row coloring template. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this is by hand using a `Rectangle` either declared before the row contents or with it's Z order set to push it to the back:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="AliceBlue" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Row 1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="AntiqueWhite" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Row 2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="AliceBlue" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Row 3" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="AntiqueWhite" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Row 4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

You might be able to use bindings to pass the row number to a converter to return the correct colour rather than hard coding like I have here.

Comment: +1 because Grid's are not actually rendered as a table, but instead are a container object which defines how to render items placed inside it. If your Grid has no objects in it, then there is nothing to use to draw the background, so you have to actually place objects inside the grid if you want this kind of behavior.

Comment: Considering your comment about using DataGrid instead of a Grid, marked as answer. However, I have some problems to display some empty Rows and Columns in a DataGrid... Cause a DataSource is necessary...

Comment: @serhio - just add empty objects to your DataSource. Though it would help if we knew what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: This worked well for me, but because I have more than one column I need to specify the Grid.ColumnSpan value.  Example: <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="AliceBlue" />